# CocoonJS Canvas image pattern fill not working

Tags: image, html5-canvas, fill, cocoonjs

I'm using HTML5 Canvas to draw a GUI.

Image pattern fill works fine in browsers (including mobile), but when I use the Cocoon JS launcher on Android or iPad, the texture pattern is just shown as black.

```
var pattern = context.createPattern(imageResource,"repeat");
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
```

Looking at the CocoonJS console, the texture is loading correctly, and **context.drawImage()** works fine with the same image.

The docs indicate that Canvas patterns are supported. Any ideas why pattern fill doesn't work in CocoonJS launcher?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Canvas patterns are supported on CocoonJS. This example works fine on CocoonJS Launcher with POT and NPOT textures:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img,"repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,300);
}
img.src = "img.png";
```

Please, share more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks - confirmed that does indeed work as a standalone test case in the launcher.

Comment: The difference is my code runs within a WebGL 3D (ThreeJS) environment, using the canvas as a bitmap source for meshes and lots of other things going on. I'll have to strip back my code and see when it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to track this down to the fact I was loading image resources *after* initialising Three JS (renderer, camera etc).

Despite the fact I was waiting for image resources to load before attempting a Canvas texture fill, if within the Cocoon launcher, I got the 'no fill' problem.

All I did was change the order of things: load image resources first, then initialise ThreeJS. Fill seems to work perfectly now within the launcher, although I'm not entirely sure why.